# what does "vcs" mean when i export a configuration

Tags: configuration

I would like to know what vcs stands for .

when i do a drush config:export, i have to choose "vcs" but I'm not sure what that means?  I am on an acquia server , does that have something to do with it?

Comment: https://docs.acquia.com/acquia-cloud/develop/config-d8/

Comment: The definition isn't to do with Drupal, but it stands for: Version Control System. As to why they chose to name the config folder with that specific acronym? [You'd have to ask Acquia](https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005216614-Acquia-vcs-config-directory-vs-Drupal-8-sync-directory)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the meaning of an acronym or about the reason why an option was named as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Drupal 8 uses the sync configuration directory type for configuration, Acquia Cloud uses the vcs configuration directory type for that purpose.